# Rasterizing in QGIS?

Tags: raster, qgis-3

I am using QGIS 3.6.3.

I am trying to rasterize 5 different maps from the same attribute table but it seems 3 of the maps produced have the same value even though they have different attribute values.

[image: 1st Picture: Attribute tables all integers]

[image: Produced Map Values]

[image: Workflow]

Comment: Can you please be more specific. It would be useful if you used some screenshots and could describe your workflow. I.E. what tools you have used, what type of data you're using etc. However, from what i have gathered here, it might be worth making copies of the vectors you are using, and manually remove fields you don't require from the attribute table to produce your maps. Thanks

Comment: I'am so sorry forgot to add pictures, the first picture shows the attribute table (The main objectives are the Cohesion, Friction angle, Soil Unit WT, Saturation and Soil Thickness). I used the rasterize tool from the processing toolbox and indicated the Attributes to be rasterized (3rd picture - Soil Thickness) but the resulting rastered maps appeared to have similar values (2nd Picture). I would try your suggestion of making copies of the vectors and see what happens. Thank you!

Comment: @LiquoriceSwift - Looks like you used the SAGA's `Rasterize` tool. Have you tried GDAL's `Rasterize (vector to raster)`?

Comment: @Joseph ah yes! I have tried the GDAL rasterize tool and it fortunately worked, thank you for your help guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be a bug in which case you could create a [new issue on their GitHub page](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Enhancement-Proposals/issues).

---

You can try other conversion tools such as GDAL's `Rasterize (vector to raster)` which can be accessed from the menubar:

```
Raster > Conversion
```

Or from the *Processing Toolbox*:

```
GDAL > Vector conversion
```